# Display results in terms of category in PHP?

Tags: php, html, categories

pals. . . I'm building up a opensource ecommerce template !

This Code below lists first 3 results of the storelist . . .

```
<?php 
  if(count($this->store_list)>0){
            $number_output = 0;
foreach($this->store_list as $store){
$number_output++;
if($number_output > 3) break;
        ?>

   <div id="menu">  
  <span class="cons_title fl"><a href="<?php echo PATH.'store/'.$store->title_url.'.html'; ?>"><h2><?php echo ucfirst($store->name); ?></h2></a></span>

             <div class="cons_bot fl clr">

                  <ul>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->address1; ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->address2; ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->area_name; ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo ucfirst($store->city_name); ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->pin; ?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4>PH:</h4><h4><?php echo $store->phone; ?></h4></li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
```

and here is the other code for displaying category wise !

```
 <?php if(count($this->category_list)>0){
            foreach($this->category_list as $category){ ?>
      <a href="<?php echo PATH;?>store-listing/cat/<?php echo $category->category_url; ?>.html" class="<?php if($category->category_url == url::title($cat_active)){ echo 'active';}?>"><?php echo ucfirst($category->category_name); ?></a>
```

and may i integrate the code below in the above code that it shows me results of a single category only . . . Can u guide me up

Comment: Have you tried to echo out count($this->category_list) to see how many you actually have? Have you tried print_r($this->category_list) to see what data you have?

Answer (score 1):

not clear which object is superior store or category

well to restrict category to only 1 do something like

```
/*possibly a parent loop to process everything over this category - if store is super*/
<?php if(count($this->category_list)>0){
         $categoryLimit = 1;
            foreach($this->category_list as $category){
                 if($categoryLimit == 1){ ?>
      <a href="<?php echo PATH;?>store-listing/cat/<?php echo $category->category_url; ?>.html" class="<?php if($category->category_url == url::title($cat_active)){ echo 'active';}?>"><?php echo ucfirst($category->category_name); ?></a>

......
<? 
  /*possibly a sub loop to process everything within this category - if store is child to category*/
                    $categoryLimit++;
                } ## end if ?>
```

hope this help